# DAYNAME + STR_TO_DATE with both DD-MM-YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY data

Tags: sql, mysql

Complete beginner here. Going through a youtube pizza sales data tutorial by [Data Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-s8c6jMRN0&ab_channel=DataTutorials) @46:32 as practice for my interview.

Youtube tutorial is using SQL Server Mgmt Studio, and I am working with MySQL workbench trying to replicate the process.

========================

**The tutorial query is this:**

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW, order_date) as order_day, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS Total_orders 
from pizza_sales 
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW,order_date)
```

[image: Tutorial query]
[image: Tutorial output]

=======================

**My side of the problem:**

[image: * pull from the table]

**The brief:**

Multiple pizza_id correlate to single order_id (multiple pizzas in same order).
order_date original data format is interchangeable as either DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY
MySQL column data (order_date) was imported as text by default. Do not understand the differences between data types, so left as default.

**My steps:**

DATENAME does not exist in MySQL, so I am using DAYNAME.
Using DISTINCT to avoid duplicate order count.
Figured I need to convert text to date, so I'm using str_to_date.

Combination of the above gave me the **best result so far:**

```
SELECT DAYNAME(str_to_date(order_date, '%d-%m-%Y %d/%m/%Y')) as Order_day, 
COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS Total_Orders from pizza_sales 
GROUP BY Order_day 
ORDER BY Total_Orders DESC
```

[image: best query]
[image: output]

Now, as far as I understand, this query is **not able to combine and pull both types of date formats** from the column, so I am either getting the '%d-%m-%Y' or '%d/%m/%Y' result, which also pulls a NULL row as one of the days in the output with 8577 orders which are not distributed between the days of the week.

**Question:**

Is there a query which would be able to display the right number of orders despite different date formats grouped by Days of the week, without altering the original file?

Comment: always always store dates in date types, not as text.  but as is, use a regexp to determine the date format to pass to str_to_date.   what does `select version ();` show?